# Unicode in Django unit test

Tags: django, unit-testing

I try to use a utf8 string in a Django unit test and have included

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

but django-admin.py still complaints there is no encoding.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in
>   
>       management.execute_from_command_line()
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 429, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py",
>   line 379, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>
> File
>   "> /home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 191, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **options.**dict**)
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py",
>   line 220, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/test.py",
>   line 8, in handle
>       super(Command, self).handle(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/test.py",
>   line 37, in handle
>       failures = test_runner.run_tests(test_labels)
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py",
>   line 358, in run_tests
>       suite = self.build_suite(test_labels, extra_tests)
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py",
>   line 248, in build_suite
>       suite.addTest(build_suite(app))
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py",
>   line 77, in build_suite
>       test_module = get_tests(app_module)
>
> File
>   "/home/basti/work/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/test/simple.py",
>   line 35, in get_tests
>       test_module = **import**('.'.join(app_path + [TEST_MODULE]), {}, {}, TEST_MODULE)
>
> SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file tests.py on line 242,
>   but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html
>   for details

The code is

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

```
"""                                                                                                                                                                                                         
This file demonstrates writing tests using the unittest module. These will pass                                                                                                                             
when you run "manage.py test".                                                                                                                                                                              

Replace this with more appropriate tests for your application.                                                                                                                                              
"""

from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.utils import IntegrityError
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode

class ViewTests(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
    self.client = Client()

   def test_french(self):
    self.client.cookies["django_language"] = 'fr'
    r = self.client.get("/")
    self.assertTrue(smart_unicode(u"Se déconnecter") in r.content)
```

I've tried to set TEST_CHARSET and TEST_DATABASE_CHARSET to utf8, but still no luck.

Any hints on how to solve that?

TIA && have a nice day!

Basti

Comment: Don't you want to show the 242nd string?

Answer (score 3):

Put:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

As the first line for that file.

Comment: If i put the comment in the first row (and not after the doc string) than I get the following traceback

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests.py", line 242, in test_something
    self.assertTrue(u"Se déconnecter" in r.content)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1196: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @BastianBallmann you should show the code for that test (update your question).

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question the problem wasn't the matching string but the encoding of the requests content!
Changing the test as followed fix it

self.assertTrue(u"Se déconnecter" in r.content.decode('utf8'))

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the encoding defined in **each** file including models and of course in tests.py. If possible, get the latest version of django.

If the administrator is still not working, try:

Solution #1:

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_unicode
```

On the model definition:

```
def __unicode__(self):  
    return smart_unicode(("%s" % self.field))
```

Solution #2: Literal method

```
def __unicode__(self):   
    return (u"%s" % self.field)
```

Always set

```
DEFAULT_CHARSET='utf-8'
```

in settings.py

You can also translate [this post][1] 
  [1]: http://www.pvilas.com/2011/03/django-evitar-error-en-el-administrador.html from spanish. I hope can help.

Comment: I tried to use smart_unicode and set DEFAULT_CHARSET to utf-8 but the error still exists

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, because in my models.py encoding was not set for the file. Putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` in my models.py and having the same in my test files solved the problem.